# Replacing Thunar in Xubuntu

Tags: xubuntu, thunar, nemo

I installed nemo and deleted Thunar in Xubuntu 14.04. Nemo was set as default manager and works fine but my problem is with the desktop. When I double click icons on the desktop in order to launch some program I get the following error:

> Failed to execute program /usr/bin/Thunar: Success

The same happens when I try to rename a file on the Desktop. Folder open at double click with no problem.
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: AFAIK Thunar manages the Xfce desktop. You need it. You can still have Nemo as the default file manager, but keep Thunar installed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In 14.04 Thunar is a core program of xfce. I really doubt you uninstalled it completely, because that would automatically remove many xfce packages, rendering xfce unusable. Thunar is like a stock app in Android, can't simply uninstall it because you break system functionality. Just put it back and live with it.

Comment: OP can still have Nemo as default FM.

Comment: Yes,  that is true.  You can have any software you want as default, just like in Ubuntu Touch or Android.

Comment: I ran sudo apt-get install thunar again and it solved the problem, thanks. I guess it is time to consider Arch ;)

Comment: @Mehdi: Thunar isn't messing your Ubuntu (core), it only messes with xfce desktop environment. If you use xfce in Arch, it will mess it too. If you use any other Ubuntu flavor (other than Xubuntu) you will have no business with thunar or xfce at all. All you have to do is change the desktop environment. Nemo is the official File Manager for the Cinnamon desktop. I don't know if Cubuntu (Ubuntu+Cinnamon) is an official flavor yet, but it ought to be really soon.

Answer (score 0):

I use Nemo instead of Nautilus as my file manager on standard Ubuntu. Desktop icons work as expected.

```
To prevent Nautilus from handling the desktop icons (and use Nemo instead), gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background show-desktop-icons false

Set Nemo as the default file manager (replacing Nautilus) xdg-mime default nemo.desktop inode/directory application/x-gnome-saved-search
```

Tested using Nemo 2.8.7 on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS